# old joomla has Strict standards errors - no access to php.ini

Tags: php, joomla

I have a few old 1.5 joomla sites that have started showing large numbers of these errors:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in /data02/eebackup/public_html/josephstorehouseuk/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 29

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in /data02/eebackup/public_html/josephstorehouseuk/libraries/loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in /data02/eebackup/public_html/josephstorehouseuk/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 32
```

I don't have access to the php.ini file and I can't login at the back end. I have tried the following:

In the configuration file:
var $error_reporting = '0'; - which left nothing but the above errors

then:
var $error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE); which again seemd to turn the site off except the above errors

and
 var $error_reporting(6351); as above

```
I tied altering 
# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

to the htacess file (note not .htaccess) and that didn't work either.

I have run out of ideas

Comment: Change hosting to hosting with lower version of php... But you know... witout upgrading your application, it will be highway to hell.

Comment: You host must have upgraded the PHP version, you may want to check that because if it's too high these will be the least of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 1.5 should be never used again. Switch to newer version

```
Version 1.5 
Release date 2008-01-22
Supported until *2012-12-01*
```

You must upgrade - also this versions have known unpatched vulnerabilities.

If you REALLY want to use that trash then

```
    ini_set('display_errors', '0');     // Hides all errors
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  // Allow logging them (if you log to the files, you should also ignore E_Strict as you already told - they will not fix it).
```

Comment: Yes iknow all that but in the realnworld there are 1000 of sites whose owners don't want ro pay out to have them updated. Often for very good reasons. So my question remains

Comment: Hi - thakns for the above. I added those lines into the config file and a lot of the errors disappeared - but still get the strict ones.

Answer (score 1):

A client who has been unable to update his Joomla 1.5 site just experienced the same error deluge. It had been running fine until the host updated PHP without warning. I did exactly what the OP said did not work (in the original post) - by adding to .htaccess

(Note: edited .htaccess, not htaccess.txt)

```
# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

and errors were immediately cleared.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do following in configuration.php 
display_errors = Off

it might possible that they are enabled anywhere in the following
php.ini
httpd.conf
.htaccess
php code

once you change in configuration.php , you only need to look php code if its enabled anywhere.
other option is to login to mysql database, you change admin password and reset the error reporting.

Last thing, you need to update your joomla 1.5 to atleast 2.5.8. 1.5 has many security breached and vulnerable, it can be hacked see here http://www.r00tsec.com/2012/07/hacked-joomla-v-16x-17x-250-252.html